# Unity3D Grid Layout Group

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, layout

**Hi**, guys I need help on grid layout group system.My problem is in resolution.I put some buttons inside the grid layout, it looks good on editor, But when I try on my device, looks bad because of different resolution how can I solve this problem?

In reference screen resolution.
https://i.hizliresim.com/MvR05a.png

*In another resolution.
https://i.hizliresim.com/Q7yaEV.png

Note: I tried content size fitter, etc..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be anchoring elements in order to layout controls inside panels, those panels should cover the same number of pixels on the screen with a small or large device.

If a requirement of yours is that the UI should actually scale to UI size, you could consider having multiple sets of image assets, picking which set to use based on the rough size of the device screen.

I'm going off having brief experience in making UIs in unity on mobile devices and, and then googling the [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html) website.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I have many games in play store without resolution problem.I know canvas scale options.. But I have trouble with grid layout group.***I edited the post, add the images.

Comment: @Dan Rayson   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535699/how-to-adjust-the-gridview-for-different-screen-sizes-in-unity3d?noredirect=1#comment96048530_54535699